# Using Qt types with ctypes and python

Tags: python, c, wrapper, ctypes, wkhtmltopdf

I want to make a kind of Python wrapper for wkhtmltopdf, build from C/C++ sources.

For this i've expected to use ctypes but wkhtmltopdf uses various structures who contain specific types like QPrinter and many others.

Does anybody knows how to use non-standard ctypes fields with Python and the ctypes module ?

I'm also searching informations about using Python-ctypes with c++ source ( .dll library) if someone knows more than me about this, i'll enjoy to learn about those things :)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use a wrapper like [py-wkhtmltox](https://github.com/mreiferson/py-wkhtmltox) instead of trying to use the C API for [libwkhtmltox](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/) via ctypes.

Comment: thanks , i've tried to install it under python 2.5, and it told me to recompile with Mingw32, i'll try to do it. I've made something that works, i call the wkhtmltopdf.exe with args & methods into a class by using the "subprocess" module. But I would prefer a wrapper :)

Comment: py-wkhtmltox **is** a wrapper; were you not able to get it to compile? I'd recommend you use Python 2.7 and the instructions for Windows (which I have verified).

Comment: Was it fast during your tests ? It lasts 6 or 7 sec for me to render a pdf , with an intel i5 processor, i've made a .exe that puts the .pyd interface and the egg info into python 2.7 (like in the instructions). I find it anormaly slow , have you an idea ? It lasts 600 ms when i call wkhtmltopdf.exe directly

Comment: I've found the reason, wkhtmltox is very slow with css gradient associated to a high DPI rendering (like it is in default settings), i got better results than with the .exe calls (~20%), just for information :) Have a nice day

Comment: And i managed to compile a .pyd for python 2.5, so i don't have to port my application to python 2.7 just for this module :) i've had to redo a libpython25.a with the types' definitions